# Troubles with ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I having trouble storing objects in an `ArrayList`.

I want to populate an `ArrayList` with a simple object called `Variable`. It has 2 string attributes: name and value. The problem is when I add a new `Variable` object to the list, the attributes of the previously added `Variable` objects appear to be null. Also, instead of being added to the end of the list, the new object is inserted at the first position.

Here is the code :

```
ArrayList<Variable> variables = new ArrayList<Variable>();

Variable author = new Variable();
author.setName("Author");
author.setValue("lusyo"); 

variables.add(author);

System.out.println(variables.get(0).getName());

Variable scenario = new Variable();
author.setName("Scenario");
author.setValue("Login"); 

variables.add(scenario);

System.out.println(variables.get(0).getName());
System.out.println(variables.get(1).getName());
```

The output is :

```
Author
Scenario
null
```

As you can see, `scenario` is located at index 0, but it should not be. I can't figure out what's going on with this code.

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Try to add 20 or so, then iterate it with a loop and tell us what the output is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Variable scenario = new Variable();
author.setName("Scenario");
author.setValue("Login");
```

Does anything disturb you there? `:)`

Answer (score 3):

You are setting the author variable attributes twice :) Once here

```
Variable author = new Variable();
author.setName("Author");
author.setValue("lusyo");
```

and later :

```
Variable scenario = new Variable();
author.setName("Scenario");
author.setValue("Login");
```

But you never set the scenario attributes.

Try this :

```
Variable scenario = new Variable();
scenario.setName("Scenario");
scenario.setValue("Login");
```

Comment: sorry, it is only a mistake I did when I copied the code

Comment: @LuSyo - Please update your question with the correct code.

Answer (score 3):

The error is there, you'll find it :

```
Variable scenario = new Variable();
author.setName("Scenario");
author.setValue("Login");
```